Passing an image to ActiveReports when using JSON data source
From my application I call an ActiveReposts rdlx report and I pass the data to this report using JSON.
Now I have a request to also pass an image to the report and display it on a report.
This image is dynamically generated by the application and I would like to avoid saving it to disc or database.
Storing the image on the disc and then recalling it is not the solution I was hoping for.
Is it possible to pass the image to the ActiveRepots report from external application and if so, how?
Has anyone done this and can point me in the right direction?

So, I did it!
All you need to do is convert your image to a Base64 string and pass it  to Report in JSON.
In the report, you need to set your image control as follows

MIMEType = image/jpeg
Source = Database
Value = Fields![FieldNameInJSON].Value

Hope this helps someone...
